# Dynamically allocate array of std::string

Tags: c++

I want to dynamically allocate an array of `std::string`. There is a function to allocate. I can call the function as many number of times as I want through out the program. If the pointer to the array is already allocated, I want to release the memory first then allocated the new one.

Here is what I tried:

```
std::string *names;
bool already_allocated = false;
void allocate( int n)
{
    if( already_allocated)
    {
        delete names;
    }
    names = new std::string[n];
    already_allocated = true;
}

int main()
{
    allocate(5);
    allocate(6);
    return 0;
}
```

But it is giving runtime error in the 2nd `allocate()` call for the line `delete names`

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<std::string>` and `resize`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `delete [] names;` because you want to delete an array of strings, `delete names;` deletes a single object.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot invoke `delete names` on an array, you should use

```
 delete[] names
```

instead.

How about use a `std::vector<std::string>` for your `names` data sructure instead?

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate memory using new you can use delete operator but when you allocate memory using new[] then to avoid memory leak use delete[] operator, to delete memory allocated for an array.

```
delete[] names
```